# Angular enable button on any input value change

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my Angular 12 application, I have a reactive form with multiple inputs and a SAVE button which submits the form. The SAVE button is disabled by default and I need to enable it only if **ANY** of the input values are edited.
I understand this can be done by calling (input) event on each of the HTML inputs but is there a more efficient way of doing this. I mean instead of writing a (input) event on each HTML input, maybe use something which would trigger if any of the inputs is changed.

My HTML Form has the following structure:

```
<form [formGroup]="profileInfoForm" (ngSubmit)="submitProfileInfoForm()">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="firstName" name="firstName
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of pristine.
Control is pristine if the user has not changed its value.

sample code

```
<button [disabled]="xyzForm.pristine"class="xyz">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `valueChanges` in your form and a boolean variable to hold the original unchanged status:

```
isFormEdited: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {

  this.profileInfoForm.valueChanges
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.isFormEdited = true;
    });

}
```

So when `isFormEdited` turns to `true`, you enable the button

```
<button [disabled]="!isFormEdited">Save</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Harris. Its working but only issue is I have this.profileInfoForm.get('firstName')?.setValue(profileData.firstName);
called in Oninit() which is calling the .valueChanges() and setting the boolean. Any workaround?
P.S I used _unsubscribeAll: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
is that ok?

Comment: Anuj's answer is better in this case, use that